# C#- How to get the days in word in computer current time instead of numbers?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datetime, days

I am building a program in windows form c# which records a daily report. I tried using `NOW();` in my MySql database and so far it works but my concern is I want only to get its Days which is not a number for example 3-15-2013(April 15, 2013), 15 is Monday instead of retrieving value 15 I want it to retrieve the word "Monday". Is that possible programmatically? Please help.

Comment: You want to get the value from c# or MySql? In c# you can use `DateTime.DayOfWeek` to get the day of week as an enum value. You can `ToString()` that to get a string representation

Comment: in C# you can do like this: DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd");

Comment: @zimdanen thank you very much that is a big help.

Answer (score 1):

If you send the date into the [DAYNAME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) function, you will get the name of the day of the week.

From the documentation:

> DAYNAME(date)
>
> Returns the name of the weekday for date. As of MySQL 5.1.12, the language used for the name is controlled by the value of the lc_time_names system variable (Section 10.7, “MySQL Server Locale Support”).
>
> mysql> SELECT DAYNAME('2007-02-03');
>
> ```
>    -> 'Saturday'
> ```

Comment: thank you this will help. but you are the one who assigned the date right? Is it possible also to get the date from your computer and use `DAYNAME`?

Comment: @user2262382: You can send in `NOW()` like you were doing, or a date from a database table.  If you're just trying to get today's day name for display on your form, I wouldn't go to the database for it - use **sha4ky**'s answer.

Answer (score 1):

In C# try use:

```
DateTime theDate = DateTime.Now;
theDate.ToString("dddd");
```

More on:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx